# How to generate rows in a table using map in react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

my code is below:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState('');
```

I am using a fake server.

```
function getTodos () {
  axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos')
  .then(function (response) {
    setTodos(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
  });
}

<tbody id="tableBody">
        {
          todos.map((item) => (
            <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{item.task}</td>
                <td>{item.desc}</td>
                <td>{item.due}</td>
                <td>{item.status}</td>
            </tr>
          ))
        }
        </tbody>
```

But I am getting this error: TypeError: todos.map is not a function

Comment: You're most likely getting this error because thanks to `const [todos, setTodos] = useState('');` when the component renders first, `todos` is a string. Use `const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use empty array default value for your `todos`

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
```

Than check what you setting in `todos` `setTodos(response.data);`

Probably error is because of default value of `todos`

Answer (score 0):

As your todos is an array [todos, setTodos] = useState('') is wrong and you need to set it to an empty array const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
And also whenever you get simillar error keep in mind that there is some problem with todos array it isnt an array or you are handling it in a wrong way